# Bypass file extension on File Inclusion Attack

Tags: php, file-inclusion

I read a ethical hacking book and I should pass a exercise. In this exercise there is a php code like this:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['p'];
    include($page.".php");
?>
```

I must access passwd by appling file inclusion attack.
I tried put %00 end of url and I can't.

Answer (score 0):

The simple Null Byte Injection depends on the current server configuation.
So maybe it's prevented because `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned On.

But there are other attack vectors too:

- Maybe your server is vulnerable to [Remote File Inclusion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Remote_File_Inclusion), and the code to access passwd is injected by remote script.
- Or some more complex LFI when path truncation hits in - please see first answer [on security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/how-can-i-use-this-path-bypass-exploit-local-file-inclusion)